# how to get list of attributes by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to get all `src` or `href` attributes on a list, from `ul` or `table`?

For example:

```
<table>
<tr>                                                                     
        <td class="ex"><a href="url1">link1</a></td>    
    </tr>
        <tr>                                                               
        <td class="ex"><a href="url2">link2</a></td>  
    </tr>
        <tr>                                                       
        <td class="ex"><a href="url3">link3</a></td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please make an attempt before asking for help

Comment: [jQuery Learn](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/) and the api are great resources to research and read to learn about what you are trying to do. But [you are expected to have made an effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), regardless of your circumstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I provide here consists on:

1. Creating two empty arrays `href_list` and `src_list` that will store the `string` values that you want to parse
2. Finding any (`'*'`) child element of `table` and `ul` that has a `href` and/or a `src` attribute.
3. If there is no attribute (`undefined`) the loop skips the element, else saves the attribute in the corresponding initial array.

```js
var href_list = [];
var src_list = [];


$('table, ul').find('*').each(function() {
  var this_href = $(this).attr('href');
  var this_src = $(this).attr('src');
  
  if (this_href !== undefined) {
    href_list.push(this_href);
  }
  if (this_src !== undefined) {
    src_list.push(this_src);
  }
});

// Print arrays
console.log(href_list);
console.log(src_list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ex"><a href="url1">link1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ex"><a href="url2">link2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ex"><a href="url3">link3</a><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="height: 2em"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks.your solution solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Provide your all anchor tag with any class name say myclass then use that class using for each  or you can use map() as mentioned by Taplar in comments below.

try this code:

```
var myarr=[ ]; 
(".myclass").each( function() { 

    var a = $(this).attr("href"); 
    myarr.push(a);
});
```

Comment: Two things.  1) The `myarr` is scoped too low and 2) the `td` already has a class they could use.  Edit: 3) This would be more applicable to `map()` than `each()`

Comment: Td has a class but I asked to add class to anchor attribute

Comment: Why though?  `.ex a` works just fine

Comment: Because he told he is 13 yrs old I made a simple example for him@Taplar

Comment: There are many ways of doing a thing.How map() is better than each()

Comment: That isn't an explanation as to why you suggest they put a class on the anchor tag.  In the long run, adding a class to the link is a small thing, but it is always a good idea to explain your suggestions.

Comment: Because `map()` is a translation method, where as `each()` is just an iterator.  `var mythings = $('.ex a').map(function(){ return this.href; }).get();` and done

Comment: Very nice example taplar but my code does the same thing  No doubt that map is faster and it returns but I did same thing in another way.

Answer (score -3):

```
$('table').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Output:

```
url1
url2
url3
```

Comment: Answers without explanations as to what was wrong and how they fixed it, are considered very low quality.

Comment: @Taplar sometimes not all answers need an explanation, especially with something very simple. just do it, and learn from trial and error.

Comment: I completely disagree.  What is "very simple" to you, is not always very simple to others.  That's the whole reason StackOverflow exists.  Explaining to others the issue they are encountering and showing them how to over come it.  Just giving them code does not explain the issue.

Comment: Yes you are right what is simple to you is not simple to others .That's why I used simple method of doing

Comment: Please don't critize if you have your ideas and logics you can provide them to needy people here.

Comment: I just want to help. nothing more, nothing less.